# warning in django_cron (Django management > commands is deprecated)

Tags: python, django, django-cron

I have this warning, when do runcrones with manage.py. Where am I doing wrong?

> site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py:345:
>   RemovedInDjango110Warning: OptionParser usage for Django management
>   commands is deprecated, use ArgumentParser instead
>   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

cron.py

from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule

```
class UnbanCron(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 5

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'board.unban_cron'

    def do(self):
        print("CRON WORKS")
```

settings of django_crone in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_bleach',
    'snowpenguin.django.recaptcha2',
    'django_cron',
    'board',
]

CRON_CLASSES = [
    "board.cron.UnbanCron",
]
```

Comment: To be honest there is nothing for you to do. Django-cron needs to be updated to make sure they do not use any deprecated code.  You can check for updates to the package. Generally it is always better use the latest version of any package.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron/issues/75) for the django-cron repository.